# Why is TestComplete so slow?

Tags: delphi, gui-testing, testcomplete

We are using TestComplete from AQTime to test the GUI at client with our Client/Server application. It is compiled with Delphi 2007. The source of client is about 1.4 millions sourcelines. The hardware is a Intel dualcore 2.13 Mhz, 2 GB RAM using Windows XP Pro.

I compile the application with all debug options and also link in TCOpenApp, tcOpenAppClasses, tcPublicInfo, tcDUnitSupport as described in documentation to make it an Open Application. The resulting exe-file is about 50 MB.

Now when running the testscript and it works, but running very very slow. The CPU is running at 100 % and it is a bit frustrating to change the testscript because of the slowness. I have turned off all desktop effects like rounded window corners. No desktop background.

Anyone else with the same experience or even an solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem probably lies in the fact you compiled with debug info and are using the tcXXX units, resulting in an enormous amount of objects being created.

A transcript from [AutomatedQA message boards](http://www.automatedqa.com/forums/d.cgi?cmd=xover&group=automatedqa.public.testcomplete&related=16599&utag=)

> Did you compile it in debug mode?  We have an app that when compiled in
>   Debug mode is slow when used with TC.  This is because of the enormous # of
>   objects in it.  If we compile w/o debug but with the TC enabler(s),
>   everything is fine.

and [this one](http://www.automatedqa.com/forums/d.cgi?cmd=xover&group=automatedqa.public.testcomplete&related=4418&utag=) might help to

> A couple of areas where you can
>   increase speed.
>
> If you are just using record and
>   playback, then look into replacing the
>   .Keys("xxx") calls to .wText = "xxx". 
>   The Keys function will use the ms
>   delay between keystrokes, while wText
>   just forces the text overwrite
>   internally.
>
> The second suggestion (which you
>   likely have already looked at) is
>   Tools->Default Project
>   Properties->Project->Playback, setting
>   the delays to 100 ms, 5 ms, and 5 ms
>   to keep the pauses to a minimum.
>
> As for the object properties, yes, TC
>   loads them all.  You can force this
>   with a process refresh on yor
>   application, so that the data is
>   forced into being available without a
>   load delay when called.  This might
>   help with reducing the appearance of
>   delay.

---

**Edit:**

- We also have been evaluating TestComplete and also encountered this performance problems. I would be very interested to know if and how you've finally solved them.
- That said, I think it is a product with great potential and can really help you with *organizing all of your unit, integration and GUI tests.*

Comment: Thanks for thew information! I will try to remove debug information and also change to other things you find. Great!

Answer (score 0):

> Now when running the testscript and it works, but running very very slow. The CPU is running at 100 % and it is a bit frustrating to change the testscript because of the slowness. I have turned off all desktop effects like rounded window corners. No desktop background.
>
> Anyone else with the same experience or even an solution ?

I recommend that you try changing the TCP ports that TestComplete use for remote connections. You can change them in the [Network Suite Options Dialog](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/33058/). For example, you can set 6100-6102 ports. Does this help? A similar issue was described in the [TC 9.20 consuming high 98% cpu](http://smartbear.com/forums/f74/t78994/tc-9-20-consuming-high-98-cpu) SmartBear forum thread.